# WolframAlpha robustness

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, wolfram-alpha-queries, missing

I am experiencing return values of `Missing[NotAvailable]` from `WolframAlpha[]`, about 10% of the time. For some reason, this seems to be happening only for a very specific query (integration), for a very specific integrand:

```
Do[Print[WolframAlpha[
    "integrate Log[RealAbs[x]]",
    {{"IndefiniteIntegral", 2},"Content"},
    PodStates -> {"IndefiniteIntegral__Step-by-step solution"}
]], 20]
```

Almost all of the time I get back the expected results, but *sometimes*, rarely, I get `Missing[NotAvailable]`.

Has anyone else experienced this inconsistent behavior? Is `WolframAlpha[]` known to have robustness issues? Is there possibly some sporadic timeout going on? Any suggestions for workarounds?

Thank you.

Comment: How reliable is your Internet connection?

Comment: J. M., great to see you well, and (as usual) commenting and contributing! :-)  My Internet connection is quite reliable. I have tried this from home, and from work, and only for this case do I see the rare, spurious, missing result.  Did you not see it happen, perhaps run the `Do[]` 50 times?  Thanx.

Comment: It fails frequently for me, because my Internet connection is slow. That's why I thought to ask you about yours.

Comment: I do see online-enabled functions fail fairly frequently.

Comment: Is there some way to programmatically "catch" that it failed due to a timeout, therefore, resubmitting it?

Comment: That sounds like it should be a separate question; it is interesting enough on its own.